# Nunit testing while using object as parameter

Tags: c#, object, parameters, nunit

I have a class "patientinfo" which include variable e.g., firstname, lastname, age, weight, height, gender .... Each of these variables have get and set methods too. 
Another class "program has following method

```
       public double weightCalc(patientinfo p3)
       {
        if (p3.getGender() == "male" || (p3.getGender() == "MALE")
            { 
                //Calculate ideal body weight
                idealWeight = (50 + (2.3 * (p3.getheight() - 60)));
            }
            else
            {
                //Calculate ideal body weight
                idealWeight = (45.5 + (2.3 * (p3.getheight() - 60)));
            }
        return idealWeight;
```

I have to prepare a test case for NUnit for this method. As I m a basic learner, expecting the ideas on how to pass the value of height or getheight in test class please

Comment: Where is gender coming from?

Comment: Sorry, it should be p3.getGender(). I missed it. Just edited. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your method is testable. Just make sure the patientinfo object can be set to the necessary values

Just define a test like this

```
[Test]
public void Will_Calculate_Correct_Weight_For_Woman()
{
   patientinfo p3 = new patientinfo();//set appropruate values here
   //Example: p3.Gender = "Woman"; or p3.setGender("Woman");
   double result = someClass.weightCalc(p3);
   Assert.AreEqual(110,result);
}
```

You have to specify the appropriate settings for your p3 instance

Comment: I got till here. But the major problem is how do i pass the value of height for testing. Do I have to ask the value with user "for testing too ?"" doesnt sound legit.